# ruby: aliased to bundled_ruby

Tags: ruby, rbenv

When I type in `which ruby` it always returns `ruby: aliased to bundled_ruby`

When I try `which bundled_ruby` it returns:

```
bundled_ruby () {
    _run-with-bundler ruby $@
}
```

Then I try `which _run-with-bundler` and it returns:

```
_run-with-bundler () {
    if _bundler-installed && _within-bundled-project
    then
        bundle exec $@
    else
        $@
    fi
}
```

Where did all this come from and how do I get my `which ruby` to work again?

I am using OSX (v10.8.2), brew, rbenv, ruby-build, zsh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is part of `rbenv` "magic" to handle several ruby versions with several gem versions. Have a look at `~/.rbenv/shims/ruby`, IIRC the script is defined there.

If you want to disable this, just `unalias ruby`: this deletes the generated alias.

Answer (score 22):

It can come from the [`bundler` plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/bundler/bundler.plugin.zsh#L50-L56) of [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

It uses magic to avoid typing `bundle exec` before the following commands: `annotate berks cap capify cucumber foodcritic foreman guard jekyll kitchen knife middleman nanoc rackup rainbows rake rspec ruby shotgun spec spin spork strainer tailor taps thin thor unicorn unicorn_rails puma`

You can disable this magic for some commands by defining the `UNBUNDLED_COMMANDS` environment variable in your ~/.zshrc before loading `oh-my-zsh` plugins (See [oh-my-zsh pull request #2195](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/2195)).

```
export UNBUNDLED_COMMANDS=ruby
# for a list of commands
export UNBUNDLED_COMMANDS=(ruby irb rake)
```

Or you can simply remove the `bundler` plugin from you `oh-my-zsh` plugins.

Comment: Quite helpful, I also like that you note where it __might__ come from and not giving a definitive answer as the OP has provided too few information about his environment. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: My buddy had this issue on his Mac and my first idea was to look on Stack Overflow, which led me to your answer, which points to a pull request that I wrote and solved the problem.

Just thought I'd share that :)

Comment: In fact I had the same issue and looked on Stack Overflow too. The proposed answer did not apply to me because I am using `rvm` and not `rbenv`. But it learned me where to search and I found that the zsh bundler plugin was the culprit. By looking at the source code, I saw the `UNBUNDLED_COMMANDS` variable and found your pull request. Once I fixed my problem I added this answer. Thanks for your work :)